# call after function several times tkinter

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I have a question about the after function and also about how it works in the `mainloop`.
I have made the code below which works and I noticed that I could call the `after` function several times. This makes the ball move quicker each time it's called. I'd like to reproduce that without pressing the button several times.

Also, could someone could explain how pressing the 'go' button several times makes the ball goes faster.

PS: Sorry for my English, I'm French...

```
from tkinter import *

def bouge():
    global speedx,speedy,run,i

    colors=["white", "black", "red", "green", "blue", "cyan", "yellow"]

    pos = can1.coords(oval1)
    if pos[0] <= 0 or pos[0] >= 450:
        speedx *= -1
        can1.itemconfig(oval1,fill=colors[i])
        i+=1
        i=i%6
    if pos[1]<=0 or pos[1]>=450:
        speedy*=-1

    can1.move(oval1, speedx, speedy)
    text1.configure(text=pos)
    if run:
        can1.after(30, bouge)

def stop():
    global run
    run=False

def start():
    global run
    run=True
    bouge()

x1, y1 = 100, 250
speedx=5
speedy=6
run=True
i=0
fen1 = Tk()
fen1.title("Arkanoid made by Rico")
can1 = Canvas(fen1, height=500, width=500,background='lightblue')
oval1 = can1.create_oval(x1, y1, x1 + 50, y1 + 50, fill='yellow')
rec1=can1.create_rectangle(225,480,275,500,fill='grey')
pos=can1.coords(oval1)
Button(fen1, text='GO!!', command=start).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=S)
Button(fen1, text='Quitter', command=fen1.quit).grid(row=2, column=3, sticky=S)
Button(fen1, text='Stop', command=stop).grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=S)
text1=Label(fen1,text=pos)
text1.grid(row=2,column=4)
can1.grid(row=1,columnspan=5)

fen1.mainloop()
```

Comment: The reason that pressing the 'go' button multiple times makes the ball go faster is because in the `bouge` function, it *schedules* itself to run again after 30ms. Every time you press the 'go' button, not only does `bouge` run, but another event is created, again calling `bouge`...

Comment: ok, how could i do that in the code? i would like to create a variable whick makes the ball accelerate without pressing the button.

Comment: If you would like the ball to move faster automatically, after an interval of say 5 seconds, you can change the global speed variables periodically (using after). Then when `rouge` runs again, it will use the new speeds. Implement another function that is called using `after`, which changes the speed values.

Comment: You can make the ball go faster either by calling `bouge()` more frequently (directly or indirectly through `after()`) **or** by changing the currently hardcoded speed (which is `1`) it uses into a variable. That way it will move the oval more each time it's called. Acceleration would just be increasing this speed each time it's called.

Comment: think i got it, will post the code just for info for anyone.

Comment: Is there a way to make multiple calls to a Tkinter function using "after" not speed up? Can I defeat it and keep the speed after one call "locked" no many how many button presses?

Answer (score 0):

```
    from tkinter import *

def speedup():
    global vit
    if vit>2:
        vit-=2
        can1.after(500,speedup)

def bouge():
    global speedx,speedy,run,i

    colors=["white", "black", "red", "green", "blue", "cyan", "yellow"]

    pos = can1.coords(oval1)
    if pos[0] <= 0 or pos[0] >= 450:
        speedx *= -1
        can1.itemconfig(oval1,fill=colors[i])
        i+=1
        i=i%6
    if pos[1]<=0 or pos[1]>=450:
        speedy*=-1

    can1.move(oval1, speedx, speedy)
    text1.configure(text=(pos,vit))

    if run:
        can1.after(vit, bouge)


def stop():
    global run
    run=False

def start():
    global run
    run=True
    bouge()
    speedup()

x1, y1 = 100, 250
speedx=6
speedy=7
run=True
i=0
vit=100
fen1 = Tk()
fen1.title("Arkanoid made by Rico")
can1 = Canvas(fen1, height=500, width=500,background='lightblue')
oval1 = can1.create_oval(x1, y1, x1 + 50, y1 + 50, fill='yellow')
rec1=can1.create_rectangle(225,480,275,500,fill='grey')
pos=can1.coords(oval1)
Button(fen1, text='GO!!', command=start).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=S)
Button(fen1, text='Quitter', command=fen1.quit).grid(row=2, column=3, sticky=S)
Button(fen1, text='Stop', command=stop).grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=S)
text1=Label(fen1,text=pos)
text1.grid(row=2,column=4)
can1.grid(row=1,columnspan=5)

fen1.mainloop()
```